# unable to understand the logic of settimeout in this piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have to hide some of subsections on click on button , here is the code

```
 $('#myButton').on('click', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#panel').hide();
    $('#header').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#sub-section').attr('style','display:none;'); }, 100);
});
```

at the last statements if I remove function set timeout then display attribute to none is not set on `#sub-section` . I just came to know about , what is actual need of settimeout here. It should work without settimeout also.

If function `hide` is taking too much time to execute , I have tried

```
$('#panel').attr('style','display:none;');
$('#header').attr('style','display:none;');
$('#sub-section').attr('style','display:none;');
```

also but it is not working. at 3rd statement only.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `display: none` will be applied to your element after `100` milliseconds. **I think** this is done because above you have called `hide` function 2 times and this function will work with animation which will take some time. So your `hide` function will finish his in approximately `less or equal to 100 milliseconds` than `display: none` will be applied

Comment: why not it is executing just after second statement.i.e without settimeout.

Comment: if hide takes time to execute , i have applied .attr('style','display:none;'); on first two statements also , but is is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you will find your answer here. and also change the timing value and observe the output then you will understand.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/mxgtaLzw/2/]
```

Without Function :

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/mxgtaLzw/3/]
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.